# Flask request security on ubuntu remote server

Tags: ubuntu, security, flask, request, remote-administration

I was testing my python flask app on a remote linux server with ubuntu 20.04 running `python server.py` without a firewall. The following then seemed to occur.

```
AA.AAA.AAA.AA - - [08/Feb/2024 16:58:44] code 400, message Bad request version ('®¯]')
AA.AAA.AAA.AA - - [08/Feb/2024 16:58:44] "Gh0st­àxKS``ÃÀÀÀÄ@¼Q   H§e&§*$&g+2ö°00¬¨rc \`&ÇK7ån9n;3¬èsch¨^Ï4'J©ã0Ãh]&øÎSËA4L?2=áÄ@õ`T®¯]" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
```

I've since activated my firewall. Please clarify as to whether my API keys, my app and the server are currently safe and whether I can safely transfer files between my ubuntu server and my local windows machine.

Comment: It's going to be hard to tell whether your server is safe from just 2 lines of log from Flask. This question is better suited for https://security.stackexchange.com/ as this is not a programming related question.